# We are not able to create/update organization repository or any POST, PUT, DELETE, operation with GitHub App Access token , getting 403 in response

Tags: rest, github, postman

[image]

We have given all the permission required from the application side.

Please find image where we are getting 403 while creating organization repository or any POST, PUT, DELETE, operation , we are able to access repo from rest api call from postman but not able to create/update/delete.
Response is :{
"message": "You need admin access to the organization before adding a repository to it.",
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository"
}

We provided all the permission required, such as the admin rights for organization and repository and all the other access, yet still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

To create repos you need to have a Github app (oauth apps are not recommended anymore), you can find info on how to create one [here](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/registering-a-github-app/registering-a-github-app). You also need to install that app on the user/organization, give this app permissions and finally [authenticate with that app](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/authenticating-as-a-github-app-installation). Only after that you can use the app to make requests to [create repos](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-an-organization-repository) or any other action. Also, be aware of the required parameters before creating your repository.

On a final note, please give a read to the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), your question could be better written and that way you could've received better help. Good luck!

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.github.com/en/rest/authentication/permissions-required-for-github-apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28#repository-permissions-for-administration, the UAT token type can be used to create Org repos but when I tried doing that I get the same error message. I tried installing and authorizing the user and using the UAT. I also tried just authorizing the user without install the app, and use the UAT. Both had the same error message. Is it strictly just for IAT token type? if so then the doc is wrong.